# Weird Coordinate System

Tags: google-maps, gps, openstreetmap, weather-api, apple-maps

I get these coordinates from a weather API which is totally undocumented :

```
"coordinates":["2615074.270000","6050614.270000"],"zoom":1
```

Do you have any idea what coordinate system it represents? How can I convert it to a lat/long system?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly certain the location is in [Romania](https://www.google.com/maps/place/47%C2%B039'39.0%22N+23%C2%B029'29.8%22E/@47.6608353,23.491612,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d47.6608353!4d23.491612).

The coordinate system [appears to be](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=3857&t_srs=4326&x=2615074.2700000&y=6050614.2700000) `EPSG:3857 WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator` and we're more used to `EPSG:4326 WGS 84` (what gmaps is using).

Tip: `proj4js` is pretty useful for converting coords. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61581958/8160318).

Comment: Sir you are correct! Thanks for saving me tons of time searching!

Comment: By any chance, do you also have a formula on how I can covert this to WGS84? I am trying to implement this on a mobile app.

Comment: No prob! I'm assuming you're using swift and there's a package that looks OK: https://github.com/fangpenlin/Proj4Swift. The pseudomercator datum found at https://epsg.io/3857 is `+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs`, WGS 84 -- https://epsg.io/4326 -- is `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs`. Plug those in and you should be good to go.